# Maximum reputation that can be lost?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I often see questions on the maximum amount of reputation that can be gained in a single day.

I would like to know the following? I would like to know more about the reputation losses.

1. Is there a limit on the reputation can be lost in a single day?
2. Is there a limit on the reputation that can be lost in a bad question? Is there a daily limit here too?
3. Is there a limit on the reputation that can be lost in a single answer to a question? Is there a daily limit here too?

Comment: No limits for losing rep.

Comment: No, no, and no. Why would there be? If you're posting *that much* crap in a single day, I think the loss of reputation would be the least of your problems. You also get back lost reputation when it gets deleted anyways.

Comment: The limit is `{your reputation score} - 1`.

Comment: This does kind of make me wonder what you're planning.  (-_-)

Comment: No worries, I was only joking.  :)

Comment: If you make enemies...then surely you will loose a lot of reputations ;)

Comment: You mean `<your reputation> + 1` @AlEverett?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are no hard limits on the amount of reputation you can lose other than the fact that everyone's reputation is floored at 1.  A few ways to lose massive amounts of reputation at once are:

1. If a post receives enough spam/offensive flags from the community (5) or from a moderator (1) it will be rewarded with -100 reputation immediately.  This is non-refundable, meaning you don't get that reputation back when the post is (immediately) deleted like you do when downvoted posts are deleted (or even if the post is *undeleted* later).
2. A user will temporarily have their reputation set to 1 when they are suspended, effectively losing all reputation until the suspension is up.
3. Placing a [bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/1288) on a question can cost up to 500 reputation.
4. You lose reputation from upvotes given by a user account that is deleted.  This is often (but not always) the case when a sock puppet has been used to artificially inflate the reputation of a main account.  (There's also an automatic process that can detect and reverse serial upvoting without deleting the account.)

Comment: @DavidRobinson Thanks. Updated to include bounties.

Comment: @juergend Thanks, I added that one as well.

Comment: How about asking a [bad question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109436/what-does-this-javascript-function-do)? Do we have to make this list any longer?

Comment: @Antony I was looking for instances where people lost more than 100 for a bad question or answer, but those all seem to be deleted, so the reputation was refunded.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Thanks, I added that on to #4, since it's closely related.  Wow, we have a lot of experts on reputation loss!  :)

Comment: @Antony That thing has been flagged *so* many times, how could I forget?  :)  Still, it somehow came out with a net reputation gain.

Answer (score 1):

1. No.
2. No.
3. No.

The only limitation that would occur that you'd probably be question banned if so many of your posts get so downvoted.